# How to get the desired signal from a photodiode and phototransistor multisim?

Tags: operational-amplifier, infrared, photodiode, modulation, phototransistor

[image]

The above is a visualization of an IR transmitter and receiver circuit I'm building. Sending a 2v and 1khz sine wave through a photodiode to a phototransistor.

[image]

The figure above shows the outputs I get from running the simulation. I send in a sine wave(blue) and a squarewave(yellow) is what I get at the phototransistor output. At the amplifier's output, I get also a squarewave(green) on the negative side of the vertical axis.

My question is how do I get a better approximate signal of the input signal from the photodiode and the phototransistor?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! please visit the [tour] page if you have not taken the [tour]. Read [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics) which gives some tips for drawing easy to understand schematics.

Comment: Photodiode is intended to use as received, not transmitter. Lignt Emission Diode is transmitter.